# How can we implement an Open with Postman button to open a postman collection link sent from a third party react application?

Tags: reactjs, postman, anchor, postman-collection-runner, open-with

I'm working with a react application and in that, I want to pass a postman collection link and open that postman collection in the postman web application. Is there any way I can try?

```
<a href="https://go.postman.co/build/workspace" target="_blank">
  <Button color="primary" autoFocus> Postman Web </Button>
</a>
```

This is the code segment I have tried so far. Here I can only open the postman web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use following url to open postman collection in the web or in the desktop app

```
https://app.getpostman.com/run-collection/{collection_id}
```

`{collection_id}` should be replaced by the id of the collection, which can be found by right clicking on the collection > share collection > get public link

For an example

```
https://app.getpostman.com/run-collection/da59a9e562ac8d63a635
```

Answer (score 0):

We can only open the collections which have a public link. To get the public link we have to first upload the collection to the postman application. Then we can have an id from the postman server.

Then,

`https://app.getpostman.com/run-collection/{collection_id}`

the above code can be used in our application.